# Get the list of azure web app settings to be swapped using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, swap, azure-web-app-service

When we perform the swap through the azure portal, it gives us the warning & informative messages regarding the settings to be swapped. Just like in below image: [image]

My question is, is there any way I can get these messages list (regarding the settings) through PowerShell code?

I tried googling it but couldn't find any way.

Comment: Try http://ruslany.net/2016/10/using-powershell-to-manage-azure-web-app-deployment-slots/

Comment: @Jayendran: In the given link, only the slot specific settings will be applied on staging slot. I want list of all slot specific & non-slot specific settings as in above screenshot. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct solution is to use the `Invoke-RestMethod` to request the API captured in the Portal. The problem is that this is a **non-public AP**I, and we don't know if it has changed.

You could use PowerShell to get the two objects to be exchanged, gets their `appSettings` and `ConnectionStrings`, and compares them. 
The following is a script for reference.

When Source and Destination are different, the script can get:
• To be added in the Destination
• The destination to be removed from the Destination
• Exchanged

```
$rsgName = "xxxxx"
$appName = "xxxxx"
$slotName = "xxxxxx"

$destination = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -Name $appName
$destinationAppSettings = $destination.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$destinationConnectionStrings  = $destination.SiteConfig.ConnectionStrings

$source = Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -Name $appName -Slot $slotName
$sourceAppSettings = $source.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$sourceConnectionStrings = $source.SiteConfig.ConnectionStrings

#Get slot configurations
$slotConfigure = Get-AzureRmWebAppSlotConfigName -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -Name $appName

$toBeAdded = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$toBeSwapped = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$toBeDeleted = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach($appSetting in $sourceAppSettings){
    if(-not $slotConfigure.AppSettingNames.Contains($sourceAppSettings.Name)){
        $flag = $true
        foreach($_appSetting in $destinationAppSettings){
            if($_appSetting.Name -eq $appSetting.Name){
                $flag = $false
                [void]$toBeSwapped.Add([pscustomobject]@{Name = $appSetting.Name; Source = $appSetting.Value; Destination = $_appSetting.Value})
            }
        }
        if($flag){
            [void]$toBeAdded.Add($appSetting)
        }
    }
}

foreach($appSetting in $destinationAppSettings){
    $flag = $true
    foreach($_appSetting in $sourceAppSettings){
        if($_appSetting.Name -eq $appSetting.Name){
            $flag = $false
        }
    }
    if($flag){
        [void]$toBeDeleted.Add($appSetting)
    }
}


# AppSettings
# To be added to destination
$toBeAdded 

# To be swapped to destination
$toBeSwapped 

# To be delete in destination
$toBeDeleted 


$toBeAdded = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$toBeSwapped = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$toBeDeleted = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach($connectionString in $sourceConnectionStrings){
    if(-not $slotConfigure.ConnectionStringNames.Contains($connectionString.Name)){
        $flag = $true
        foreach($_connectionString in $destinationConnectionStrings){
            if($_connectionString.Name -eq $connectionString.Name){
                $flag = $false
                [void]$toBeSwapped.Add([pscustomobject]@{Name = $connectionString.Name; Source = $connectionString.Value; Destination = $_connectionString.Value})
            }
        }
        if($flag){
            [void]$toBeAdded.Add($connectionString)
        }
    }
}

foreach($connectionString in $destinationConnectionStrings){
    $flag = $true
    foreach($_connectionString in $sourceConnectionStrings){
        if($_connectionString.Name -eq $connectionString.Name){
            $flag = $false
        }
    }
    if($flag){
        [void]$toBeDeleted.Add($connectionString)
    }
}


# ConnectionStrings
# To be added to destination
$toBeAdded 

# To be swapped to destination
$toBeSwapped 

# To be delete in destination
$toBeDeleted
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Joey Cai: I really appreciate your efforts and I think your solution will work (although I didn't try). But I was searching for any direct API.

I think currently there is no direct command let or API