# How to access azure portal’s configuration from devOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I’ve configured some environmental variables for my web app under azure portal’s “configuration > environmental variable” section. (portal.azure.com)

Now I need these variables in devOps during pipeline execution.

Note: I can’t hardcode environmental variables directly in devOps itself (pipeline variables) due to organizations security restrictions.

Also, saw that I can use key vault for this purpose, still keyvault needs a url and secret, which got to be hard coded in devOps.

Any idea on how to consume the environmental variables in devOps directly from azure portal’s configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate Azure Key Vault with Azure DevOps Variable Groups. Here is an article on how to do it: https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/

Additionally, you can use the Azure Key Vault Task in Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks @Nilay, but is there any possibility to access the environmental variables available in "Appservice > Settings > Configuration > Application Settings" from devOps directly, without using keyvault.

Comment: No you can't access your web app configuration from an Azure DevOps pipeline. You could however get this via a powershell task with a small custom script and get this information via the Azure APIs. However, the idea is to push all your configuration from your pipeline and not modify your configuration from the portal.

Comment: @msg if this answers your question, please mark it as an answer :)

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671347/get-the-list-of-azure-web-app-settings-to-be-swapped-using-powershell