# Subscription-id, resourceGroupName and name of the App from inside the web-app PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have an application hosted in Azure PAAS. The connection string for the application is stored under `'Configuration' -> 'Connection strings'`

My application has a PowerShell instance. I want to iterate through all the Connection strings present under `'Configuration' -> 'Connection strings'`

I have seen the [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-connection-strings). As my application itself is the app, can there be a way to skip the details like 'subscriptionId', 'resourceGroupName' and 'name'?
This will help to make the code more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As my application itself is the app, can there be a way to skip the
> details like 'subscriptionId', 'resourceGroupName' and 'name'?

***AFAIK, Its not possible to acquire the connection strings using Rest API, or PowerShell of an Azure web application without providing Resource group name or subscription.***

The [***MS DOCUMENT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-connection-strings?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0) *you have followed is to list the connection strings which is correct but we need to pass those credentials to achieve the same*.
[image]

*If my understanding is correct as its your own application and if its publicly hosted then anyone will not be able to get the resource group name, application name(If you are using custom domain) or subscription details.*

***Alternatively***, *we can use the [**`Az cli`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/connection-string?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-connection-string-list) by providing the resource group only* :-
[image]
For more information please refer the below links:-

- **SO THREAD**|***[Get the list of azure web app settings to be swapped using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671347/get-the-list-of-azure-web-app-settings-to-be-swapped-using-powershell)***

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the REST API calls for your code, then the simple answer is just: No.
I think in all cases the answer is going to be no honestly..

You can't drop those unique IDs, because those are required parameters to retrieve the correct data.
If you want to make the code more generic, then you should write the code to retrieve the values for those parameters. Instead of hardcoding the values.

Your powershell code will always need to authenticate, or use a Managed Identity, and the identity used to authenticate will always have the subscriptionid as value in its object. As for the rest, well i think you get the gist of what im suggesting.